# Importing password hash to Auth

Tags: django, django-authentication

I wrote an script to import user information from my old site database to my new django database. I should be able to import theses fields: user, email and password.

All passwords users on my old database are hashed with "md5". So... I should get this "md5" hashed password and save as they are on my auth_user database. However, I dont know how to do it without hash it again....

How can I do that?

If I do...

```
u = User.objects.create_user(user_name,email)
u.set_password(old_pass)
u.save()
```

the password is hashed again... How can I save a "pure" password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just directly set the `password` attribute.

```
u.password = old_pass
```

The `set_password` function is intended as a helper to use because `u.password = 'some_pass'` will just store the password directly in human-readable form -- it doesn't apply here since you already have the hashed password.